# voice recording & editing with npm, nodejs & angularjs

Tags: angularjs, npm, editing, voice-recording

I would like to use npm packages with angularjs for editing a voice that recorded. The actions that I need, are select, cut, copy, paste, move a part of that sound a part of sound. I can not find any resource about this case.

I used react for recording but I can't find any voice editing.

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry but flagged as off-topic. So is not for library or software recommendations

Comment: Qestion edited. @AllTheFish

Comment: Well I do not think that this will help. Anyway this is what a well know search engine comes up with: [web-audio-api](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api). I am pretty sure there is more out there! Try searching for 'node js edit audio' or something similar.

Comment: I do it, but with angular I can't find anything. @AllTheFish